# Dynamic loading of inputs

Tags: c, scanf

I am new in c programming and i need to scan inputs in cycle and validate them as i scan them.
I try to achieve something like this:

In cycle from 0 to n, for every n type 4 inputs, then press enter validate them (if they are wrong then end program) then continue to type another 4 inputs (new line)...

Basicly input is this:

1 2 3 4 (enter)(if ok -> cursor next line)

7 5 6 8 (enter) ....

over and over till n.

```
int i=0;
while (i <= n){
     if(scanf("%d %d %d %d",&array[i],&array[i+1],&array[i+2],&array[i+4])!=4) return 0; 
    i+=5;
}
```

This program ends after i press enter.

Thank anyone for help.

Comment: what is the value of n? do you type 4 values? If your n is less than 5 then the program will end after the first input. Why is your last argument `&array[i+4]` and not `&array[i+3]`?

Comment: n should be always higher than 5 , i type 4 values, i+4 is because i need that free index for future use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use another counter for your loop since `i` is for the index of the array.

If `n` is the number of time you want to make 4 inputs then the array has to be allocated accordingly (in multiples of 5). Also you should use less than n `<` not less that equal if your counter start with `0`.

Here the variable `c` is used for the while condition.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 

int main(int argc, char** argv)  
{ 
    int n = 5;
    int array[n*5]; // mult 5 because of i+=5 / 4 inputs at onece + 1 rserved
    int i=0;
    int r = 0, c = 0;
    while (c < n){
        printf("type four ints: ");
        r = scanf("%d %d %d %d",&array[i],&array[i+1],&array[i+2],&array[i+4]);
        if(4 != r) {
            printf("bad input, program will exit: %d\n", r);
            return EXIT_FAILURE; 
        }
        i+=5;
        c++;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;  
}
```

Comment: Last argument seems to be `&array[i+3]`.

Comment: @SunEric, already asked that in comment on question, `i+3` is reserved "for future use"!